# Reading messages dynamically in Java1.6

Tags: java, properties

I've multiple messages file (`messages_en.properties`, `messages_ch.properties`)

These files are having some static html text & need some dynamic input param such as `username` so that it'll say `Dear {0}, thanks for subscription....`

Now i need to substitute `username` there after reading those contents from appropriate file.

How can I do that in Java? Is there any framework sample code available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [I18N trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageFormat.html). Nutshell version from that tutorial, using newer API methods:

```
    ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessageBundle", Locale.getDefault());
    String output = MessageFormat.format(messages.getString("msg.key"), "Mike");
```

Depending on your actual usecase there may be some shortcuts (e.g., web frameworks often include direct support for localization via tag libraries, some libraries wrap up some busywork, etc.)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Fixed; was streamlining the trail's code and forgot to change that.

Comment: Just a point, constructing a `MessageFormat` is only appropriated when you want to format repeatedly (optionally changing patterns) with the one argument `format` method. Please do not use static methods through object instances. Either use `className.staticMethodName` or [Static Import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html). I'm upvoting anyway, but would be happy if you fix the example for further reference.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Now the comments are out of sync.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Uh, I know how to use the site.

Comment: You sure come across as unpleasant. Carry on.

Answer (score 2):

Check [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) out:

```
String result =  MessageFormat.format(
   "Dear {0} , thanks for subscription....", username);
```

You can combine it with [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) `getString` method to read the message from your properties files through its key and output the formatted, dynamically filled message.

Comment: Will it work with the properties file which has HTML tags. How do I combine the remaining message string? Can you provide code sample?

Comment: @Mike The message contents are irrelevant.

Comment: Yes it will. If you have valid properties files in the `key=value` pair format, it doesn't matter if value contains html tags. Check @Dave answer and I18n trails link for examples.